# Which Juju's OpenStack Charms am I using (Community or Canonical)?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, canonical, landscape

To give you better idea, let me just give you a little context

- I had a MAAS setup with 6 nodes in ready state.
- One of my node became Juju bootstrap node.
- After that I deployed OpenStack Juju charms by following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure.
- I can successfully log into dashboard.

**Question**: I am confused about the distribution of OpenStack which was deployed by following above steps. I am not sure about Whether its Community distribution or is it recently released ["Canonical Distribution"](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/10/28/introducing-the-canonical-distribution-of-ubuntu-openstack-your-autopilot-for-rapid-customised-openstack-private-cloud-deployment-and-management/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu OpenStack: the Canonical distribution deploys OpenStack in Canonical's reference architecture. The mechanism through which you install OpenStack uses Landscape to talk to MAAS and Juju and deploy the charms in that architecture. You get added benefit from Landscape doing the work because it helps you monitor your OpenStack setup after it's installed.

By following the instructions on the help site, you've got an OpenStack install, but it's in the architecture that you've defined.

In short: you don't have the Canonical distribution.

Comment: Thankyou both Adam and Felipe for your answers :). I wanted to give you +1, but I can't do so because it requires me to have 15 reputation :(.

Comment: By following the instructions on the help site, you've got an OpenStack install, but it's in the architecture that you've defined.

Comment: I am still not sure that from where I can get the "Ubuntu Openstack: The Cannonical distribution"?

Comment: Based on your other question I think you found it, but for future readers: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is the link which I am following on my other machine.
Can you please elaborate that how Canonical's reference architecture is different than "mine" architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Juju charms for OpenStack deployment by default use the packages available in the distribution, for instance if you deploy trusty then you're getting Icehouse packages being pulled from the Ubuntu archive.

The "Canonical Distribution" is based on the same packages, but is deployed in a standard reference architecture by Landscape automation, and is a brand associated with using Ubuntu technologies within Canonical's best practices.

Best,